# Looking for a character's name

Tags: myth-identification

I recently heard a reference to a character the gods sentenced to live long enough to see the results of his bad advice. I am looking for a reference for this story, specifically the name of the character and the god who sentenced him. No results on web searches, not sure where to look.

Comment: Hello. This is incredibly broad, I don't know how much help we can be without further info. Isn't there anything else you can tell us about the story? Even a vague hint about the culture could help narrow this down.

Comment: @yannis Unfortunately the reference was vague. I am still searching for the story and source.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Gibet . Yeah, those don't sound like what I am looking for.   I am beginning to wonder if it was a made up reference. Hope not. I am on the road for a few weeks but plan to get into this more when I'm at home and can dig in deeper. Appreciate your notes.

Comment: 'Kakbhushundi' - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakbhushundi#Life